# Want to send a request get in python from different country

Tags: python, get, request, http-get

So I want to scrape details from https://bookdepository.com
The problem is that it detects the country and change the prices.
I want it to be a different country.
This is my cost, I run it on real.it and I need the book depository website to think I'm from Israel.

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}
bookdepo_url = 'https://www.bookdepository.com/search?search=Find+book&searchTerm=' + "0671646788".replace(' ', "+")
search_result = requests.get(bookdepo_url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(search_result.text, 'html.parser')
result_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_= "book-item")
```

Comment: The server will see the client IP, and no amount of messing about with the request headers is going to change that.

Answer (score 2):

You would either need to route your requests through a proxy server, a VPN, or you would need to execute your code on a machine based in Israel.

That being said, the following works (as of the time of this writing):

```py
import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def make_proxy_entry(proxy_ip_port): 
    val = f"http://{proxy_ip_port}" 
    return dict(http=val, https=val) 

headers = {
  "User-Agent": (
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
      '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
}

bookdepo_url = (
    'https://www.bookdepository.com/search?search=Find+book&searchTerm='
    '0671646788'
)

ip_opts = ['82.166.105.66:44081', '82.81.32.165:3128', '82.81.169.142:80',
           '81.218.45.159:8080', '82.166.105.66:43926', '82.166.105.66:58774',
           '31.154.189.206:8080', '31.154.189.224:8080', '31.154.189.211:8080',
           '213.8.208.233:8080', '81.218.45.231:8888', '192.116.48.186:3128',
           '185.138.170.204:8080', '213.151.40.43:8080', '81.218.45.141:8080']

search_result = None
for ip_port in ip_opts:
    proxy_entry = make_proxy_entry(ip_port)
    try:
        search_result = requests.get(bookdepo_url, headers=headers,
                                     proxies=proxy_entry)
        pprint.pprint('Successfully gathered results')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pprint.pprint(f'Failed to connect to endpoint, with proxy {ip_port}.\n'
                      f'Details: {pprint.saferepr(e)}')
else:
    pprint.pprint('Never made successful connection to end-point!')
    search_result = None

if search_result:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(search_result.text, 'html.parser') 
    result_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_= "book-item")
    pprint.pprint(result_divs)
```

This solution makes use of the request library's `proxies` parameter. I scraped a list of proxies from one of the many free proxy-list sites: http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/IL/

The list of proxy IP addresses and ports was created using the following JavaScript snippet to scrape data off the page via my browser's Dev Tools:

```js
console.log(
    "['" +
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td>font.spy14'))
    .map(e=>e.parentElement)
    .filter(e=>e.offsetParent !== null)
    .filter(e=>window.getComputedStyle(e).display !== 'none')
    .filter(e=>e.innerText.match(/\s*(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s*:\s*\d+\s*/))
    .map(e=>e.innerText)
    .join("', '") +
    "']"
)
```

*Note*: Yes, that JavaScript is ugly and gross, but it got the job done.

At the end of the Python script's execution, I do see that the final currency resolves, as desired, to Israeli New Shekel (ILS), based on elements like the following in the resultant HTML:

```
<a ... data-currency="ILS" data-isbn="9780671646783" data-price="57.26" ...>
```